# How to show ListView.builder with bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I want to showing list of items with ListView.builder. My code is success connect to API, but the problem is I do not know how to display the items, instead the length of the items.

Here I attach the code:

```
                  child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.Food.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Row(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                                width: 10,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  foregroundColor:
                                      ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                state.Food.length.toString(), //The problem is here----------
                                style: subtitle1(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: You can access each item in excavator list by `state.excavator[index].propName`.

Comment: If you need to access each item multiple times you can write at the start of the itemBuilder method something like `final item = state.excavator[index]`. Then, you can use it like `item.propName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

> ```
> Text(
>    state.food.length.toString(),
>    style: subtitle1(),
> ),
> ```

use the index of the list builder

> ```
> Text(
>    state.food?[index].attributeName ?? 'No value',
>    style: subtitle1(),
> ),
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As you are iterating over the Listview, it gives you `index` to access the property of the individual iterated item , using `index` you can display the item.

Example:

```
 Text(state.Food[index].propName, //  change the propName to any property of Food model
   style: subtitle1()),
```